# How and where to store toolbox tools (C# Visual studio 2013 Ultimate)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm a beginner programmer doing my very first program for my IT Diploma. Therefore, please forgive me for any amateur errors I may make. The program is a C# Windows Forms Application.

Edit: this is my final project.

One of my program's functions is for the user to create a checklist. In order to do this, I decided to use a button to add the checklist items onto a Flow Layout Panel. But I'm stuck on how and where to store it.

Edit: They can save the checklist(s). And when they reopen the program, they 
      should be able to access it again.

I looked up a few related topics and I got these two results: as an external file or in the database. The external file thing feels a little too tedious given my time frame (end of June 2020) and a lot of people out there don't seem to agree with storing objects in a database.

Edit: I'm using the built-in MS SQL Database.

So, back to my question: how and where can my program store all the checklists that the user will be making?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using VS 2013?

Comment: Quick and dirty. Write a class(es) to hold the data. Serialise to json store as file when the app closes, Load said file and deserialse when the app opens. There's no good answer to your question though.

Comment: @mjwills Okay, that didn't help. But if you need to know, the lecturer told us to use 2013 specifically. Don't judge me based on that. I have VS 2019. That aside, any ideas you can give me?

Comment: If you already have a database, then store it in there. If not, then using a file seems sensible. You say _store all the checklists that the user will be making"_ - does this mean you're reloading all previous checklists, or just storing the 'current' one?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Thank you. I'll try this out.

Comment: @stuartd Yeah. They will save the checklist. And then when re-opening, they should be able to open it again.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some easy configurable database, like Mongodb to store the list in there.
It saves it as Bzon files(json) despite of the model construction.

This guy explain pretty well how to use MongoDb CRUD Operations with WinForm app:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZpEwre2TG7A&list=PLaI59Szei4fmCmmYbOBFII2Ukvn8nwNUK&index=3

Comment: If you want get to know more about mongodb I recommend one of the Tim Corey's video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69WBy4MHYUw

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to store the items user created, you can achieve it by using [Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings).

Fisrt, open `Settings` by the steps `Project -> Properties -> Settings` and add a new Setting "CheckList".

[image]

Then refer to the following demo to read/write Setting.

```
string strlist = "";

private void btAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkedListBox1.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    strlist = Properties.Settings.Default.CheckList;
    if (Properties.Settings.Default.CheckList != "")
    {
        List<string> list = Properties.Settings.Default.CheckList.Split('|').ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            checkedListBox1.Items.Add(list[i]);
        }
    }
}

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    strlist = "";
    foreach(string i in checkedListBox1.Items)
    {
        strlist += i + "|";
    }

    Properties.Settings.Default.CheckList = strlist;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

The test demo:

[image]

Comment: Use the [StringCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection?view=netcore-3.1) type instead of the `string` type to store/retrieve string items.

Comment: @JQSOFT Yes, that is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to start you down the path of the wonderful answer of "It Depends".  Since this is homework for a class I would ask the lecturer if you need to store it between application restarts.

If you do, a database is way more than you need.  Using serialization and a flat file is easier and if you need to have things survive app restarts it has no requirements other than write access to the drive.

Using XML or JSON you would serialize the data class to the text string then store the text in the file.  To load you would reverse the functions and populate your data into the application.

Comment: Final project, actually. My question also included *how*. If I were to use the database, how do I get my tools into it? Is there a certain data type I should use?